# Can i get virus/trojan from cracked software when my windows is installed with avg 2015

Tags: virus, trojan, avg-antivirus

One of my colleages says that he is free from virus/trojan from cracked softwares as long as the PC has AVG 2015 free edition installed.

Is it correct?

Comment: No;  Its not true.  If it was true.  The security industry wouldn't be a multi-Billion dollar industry and everyone would use AVG which by the way is one of the worst security products on the market.

Comment: Short Version: Yes, you can. Are you more at risk of it happening by using pirated software and dodgy cracks? Yes, you are. :)

Comment: I encourage you to tell your colleague he isn't a fool though.  Anyone that uses pirated software and steals from hard working developers deserves to be infected with malicious software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An anti-virus software would prevent your computer to be infected with many kinds of virus as long as its treat recognition databases match the potential treat's signature, but it can't possibly know all the different viruses that are out there, so stating that *he is free from virus/trojan* is plain wrong.

There's also another kind of malicious software, called malware, that most anti-viruses aren't aware of, and would let them pass through their protection without any alert. This so-called malware is just like any other regular software, but serves another purpose. That's why there is anti-malware software, these special kind of protection keeps a different kind of signature database that best fits malware's behaviours.

So the ideal thing would be to have both anti-virus and anti-malware protection, but the best is to always have common sense and avoid downloading stuff from non-trusted sites.